# The reference of external values in Garbled Circuit

Tags: garbled-circuits

Is anyone aware of the source for a technique that incorporates external wire values into Garbled Circuits? I have come across this technique, which can be found [here](https://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/%7Ensmart/FHE-MPC/Yao.pdf). However, I was unable to locate the primary reference for it.

The purpose of this technique is to reduce the number of decryption operations required during the evolution phase. By incorporating external wire values into Garbled Circuits, the technique aims to optimize the process and improve efficiency. Unfortunately, the primary reference for this technique is currently unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That PDF uses the expression "external value" to refer to a particular bit in the wire label that is used for the "point-and-permute" technique. In [this video](https://youtu.be/FTxh908u9y8?t=828) I call them "color bits". The technique originated in [Beaver-Micali-Rogaway 1990](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/100216.100287). The name "point-and-permute" (or "permute-and-point") is from [Kolesnikov 2005](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Evlad/papers/GESS_AC05Proceedings.pdf). The point-permute technique is used in essentially every garbled circuit technique since 1990 (I know of only one exception that is incompatible with point-permute).